# Bouncing ball invalid syntax why is that?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n = 5000     # number of data points to plot
start = 0.0 # start time, s
end = 4500.0   # ending time, s
g = -8.87    # acceleration, m*s**-2

t = np.linspace( start,end,n+1,dtype=np.float(64)    # time, s
y = np.zeros( n+1 )                 # height, m
v = np.zeros( n+1 )                 # velocity, m*s**-1
y[ 0 ] = 250000                        # initial condition, m
v[ 0 ]=0
bounce=0.0
for i in range( 1,n+1 ):
    v[ i ] = v[ i-1 ] + g*( t[ i ]-t[ i-1 ] )
    y[ i ] = y[ i-1 ] + v[ i-1 ] * ( t[ i ]-t[ i-1 ] )

    if y[ i ] <= 0:
        bounce+=1
        v[ i ] = -0.9*v[ i-1 ]
        y[ i ]=0
plt.plot( t,y )
plt.show()
```

why do I have Invalid Syntax for y=np.zeros(n+1)?
I want to calculate how many time the ball bounces in 1 hour and 15 minutes from a height of 250km and lose 10% of velocity every time it bounces

Comment: closing parenthesis on the line above

Comment: In Python, whenever you get a mysterious syntax error on a line that is obviously correct, look back a line or two, because you are almost certainly missing a closing parenthesis, bracket or other delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a paren on this line:

```
t = np.linspace( start,end,n+1,dtype=np.float(64)
```

should be:

```
t = np.linspace( start,end,n+1,dtype=np.float(64))
```